# Htaccess rewriting upload directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Files in the `/upload` directory aren't being display (images). I tried adding a rule matching `^upload/(.*)$` with the `L` flag before the last rule I have now, but that didn't work. Removing the `./` before `index.php` and not setting a `RewriteBase` didn't work either.

Basically, for some reason both the `RewriteCond` seem to be failing causing the files that do exist in the files to be redirected to `index.php`

Am I doing something wrong? It worked great before I updated PHP today.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and what exact problem are you facing?

Comment: The .htaccess is in `public_html` just like the `upload/` directory, but as seen on [the website](http://cultureforfriends.eu/) all the images seem dead and when visiting them you're redirected to index.php

Comment: Does `upload/` also have a .htaccess? Try changing `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to `REQUEST_FILENAME`

Comment: `It worked great before I updated PHP today`.There has to be more to it than that. What else was done on the server?

Comment: PHP was updated, mysql was updated, phpmyadmin was updated. Maybe a minor Apache version slipped in? I updated using DirectAdmin's custombuild so I'm not 100% sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out to be custombuild rewriting the configs causing some weird behavior all across the server. Restored the configs from backup and all was good.